# How can I use IntelliJ and Maven to build a Gatling script?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gatling

My main issue is getting the message "**Error: Could not find or load main class Engine**"

**How and when**: I am trying to run an Engine class from a Udemy Gatling 3 Fundamentals class after importing the POM file.

**Details:** Java jdk1.8.0_241
         IntelliJ 2019.3
         Maven 3.6.3

So... I am not even qualified to call myself a "Newbie". But I want to start using Gatling instead of LoadRunner.

About six months ago I was able to use IntelliJ and Maven to set things up. However, now, with IntelliJ 2019.3 I cannot get things to work. After installing Maven 3.6.3 and IntelliJ, I import a POM file from a Gatling 3 Fundamentals class. I then try to run the Engine class.

Thoughts from anyone. I should not need to be an expert in three different tools to run one simple test. Please remember:

- I am a tester not an architect.
- I do not write Scala.
- I do not write Maven.
- I do not use IDE's.
- I do not speak Hindi or any of the 38 Indian languages.
- I do not know SBT from SQUAT.
- I barely can write Java.
- I am old and cranky.
- I have been trying to learn how to build one Gatling script since November.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Have you installed the IntelliJ plugin for Scala?

Answer (score 0):

The `Engine` class runs after the following configuration changes:

1. [Add Scala SDK 2.12.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0DM1.png)
2. Configure `src/test/scala` as [the test sources root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFCSD.png)
3. Increase [Scala compiler server stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1chhe.png) size by adding `-Xss100M` option.

[Proof of working in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SVuJ.png).

If you want IntelliJ IDEA to configure the test sources root automatically and also build this project from the command line Maven, you have to use the [scala-maven-plugin](https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_compile.html).

[Gatling documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/installation/#with-maven) has more details:

```
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
      <configuration>
         <jvmArgs>
          <jvmArg>-Xss100M</jvmArg>
        </jvmArgs>
        <args>
          <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
          <arg>-deprecation</arg>
          <arg>-feature</arg>
          <arg>-unchecked</arg>
          <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
          <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
        </args>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After running `scala:testCompile` goal [the classes appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNpY.png) in the `target` directory.

Here is the complete [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/raw/WksnAwyJ) file that you can use.

Comment: You don't need build-helper-maven-plugin if your project is pure Scala. Just set <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory> like explained in official documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/current/installation/#with-maven

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE thanks for the hint, I've updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use maven, don't know how to code, don't know how to use an IDE, why would you want to go with using Gatling this way?

Use [Gatling's zip bundle distribution](https://gatling.io/docs/current/installation/#using-the-bundle), use a text editor with syntactic coloration for Scala (eg [Nodepad++](https://github.com/scala/scala-tool-support/tree/master/tool-support/notepad-plus)) and execute Gatling from the command line.

Comment: I am trying to use Maven, Java code and an IDE because I know that the people that I will be trying to show Gatling will be going that direction. I want them to test their code, and Gatling is the best choice. But if it does not "fit" their normal behavior, they will continue to simply not test.